# AngularJS GULP BrowerSync Error: ENAMETOOLONG, name too long

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need your help with this famous angular JS project that I downloaded from git. https://github.com/thaiat/famous-flickr

When i run gulp browser sync and I get this ENAMETOOLONG error and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
aj$ gulp browsersync
[23:45:56] Using gulpfile ~/famous-flickr/gulpfile.js
[23:45:56] Starting 'browserify'...
[23:45:56] Finished 'browserify' after 23 ms
[23:45:56] Starting 'fonts'...
[23:45:56] Finished 'fonts' after 3.37 ms
[23:45:56] Starting 'style'...
[23:45:56] Starting 'style:watch'...
[23:45:56] Finished 'style:watch' after 7.39 ms

fs.js:438
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENAMETOOLONG, name too long '/Users/famous-`flickr/client/styles/data:application/json;base64,

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at fromSource (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/utils/input-source-map-tracker.js:67:31)
    at InputSourceMapStore.track (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/utils/input-source-map-tracker.js:137:5)
    at Object.whenDone (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:96:44)
    at processNext (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:105:13)
    at importFrom (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:79:10)
    at ImportInliner.process (/Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:36:10)
    at /Users/DhanLalRaj/famous-flickr/node_modules/gulp-minify-css/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:71:41
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)
```

Comment: I had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a problem that can come up with map files during the minification process.  See https://github.com/FlagshipWP/compass/issues/29 where that project ran into a similar problem.

A solution that worked for me was to simply suppress sass from creating  map files.  If you have a gulp project just set the configuration parameters for sass:

```
<...>
.pipe(sass, mainSass, {
    sourcemap:false,
    loadPath: ['resources/bower_components']
}) 
<...>
```

If you run sass from the command line it would be:

```
sass blahblahblah.css --sourcemap=none
```